# How can I use TensorFlow on Windows with AMD GPU?

Tags: windows, installation, tensorflow, gpu, amd-gpu

I want to use TensorFlow on Windows (Win 10) with a AMD GPU.

If I google, there are a lot discussions and sources but I just couldn't figure out what's the best way to do this at the moment.

**Could someone write a short installation instruction** that he thinks is the best and most up-to-date way of doing so?

Comment: This could be a repeat of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37892784/using-keras-tensorflow-with-amd-gpu

Comment: @GavinBrelstaff: The question is from June 2016. It's probably not up-to-date. Also this questions searches for a solution for Keras and for OSX. I can't see any relation else than we are using the same GPU.

Comment: I don't believe this is possible at the moment

Answer (score 2):

Tensorflow officially only supports CUDA, which is a proprietary NVIDIA technology. There is one unofficial implementation using openCL [here](https://github.com/hughperkins/tf-coriander) which could work, or you could try using Google colab

Answer (score 0):

Had exactly the same problem 6 years later. System: Win 10 Pro, 64 bit, AMD Ryzen 5 PRO 5675U

Now there is Tensorflow2. [Here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install) are the installation instructions. I used the pip instructions and had it installed in a couple of minutes. I thought I'd share it to save others the time I spent searching for a solution.

```
# Requires the latest pip
pip install --upgrade pip

# Current stable release for CPU and GPU
pip install tensorflow
```

Beforehand I installed WSL2 in the Windows Powershell `wsl --install`  ( [instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install) ). Windows also has [instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/ai/directml/gpu-tensorflow-wsl). They might be useful to somebody else.

Up-date 2024-02-16 following Spenhouets comment:
Indeed I have an AMD Radeon GPU :-). Though the GPU was produced by a third party company in the USA.  [Here instructions](https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/faq/gpu-55) how to check your GPU in the device manager and also how to find out the manufacturer of your GPU.

Comment: You do have a AMD GPU?

Comment: No - I love spending time on problems that I don't have because I do not know what else to do with myself.... O.k. sarcasm aside. Course I do. Thought it was self-evident...

Comment: Sorry for asking so indirectly. You just had listed your AMD CPU, and I assume you are running tensorflow on your CPU and not on your AMD GPU, because the current documentation suggests that running with an AMD GPU is still a lot of work to get running, though it seems that there are options today, not like when I asked that question. Today I neither use AMD nor Tensorflow. But simply installing tensorflow and having it run on your AMD GPU, is not what a quick Google search suggests is possible today. Else I would have marked your answer, but I have no way of verifying.

Comment: Spenhouet - true a quick Google search doesn't reveal this solution. I did several different ones and emptied my cache in-between before I found this solution. It was the only one working. Hence my comment about saving others time. Whether it runs on my AMD CPU or GPU I cannot tell for certain as the Tensorflow instruction says * Current stable release for CPU and GPU*. Important bit for me is whether it works and does what it is supposed to do.

Comment: You can check your GPU load during a training run. I'm sure it's just running on your CPU. And it matters, as this question was for GPU, since getting Tensorflow to run on an AMD CPU was always as easy as just installing Tensorflow, also back when I asked that question. This question is hard to answer because most deep learning frameworks rely on CUDA, and CUDA is NVIDIA tech. Back then there where mostly no options to get it to run with an AMD GPU (which does not run CUDA). Today there seem to be some (complicated) options. Training on a GPU is much faster, so you should care.