# TensorFlow GPU Support Mac - OpenCL

Tags: macos, tensorflow

Does `TensorFlow` have GPU support for a late 2015 `mac` running an `AMD Radeon R9 M370X`

```
AMD Radeon R9 M370X:
Chipset Model:  AMD Radeon R9 M370X
Type:   GPU
Bus:    PCIe
PCIe Lane Width:    x8
VRAM (Total):   2048 MB
Vendor: ATI (0x1002)
Device ID:  0x6821
Revision ID:    0x0083
ROM Revision:   113-C5670E-777
Automatic Graphics Switching:   Supported
gMux Version:   4.0.20 [3.2.8]
EFI Driver Version: 01.00.777
Metal:  Supported
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Keras & Tensorflow with AMD GPU](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37892784/using-keras-tensorflow-with-amd-gpu)

Comment: There's no support for AMD on MacBook (and possibly there will never be). There's a bit of hope for AMD on Linux though

Answer (score 1):

OpenCL is currently not supported.

You can follow the progress here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/22

Comment: The latest update on the SYCL implementation enabling TensorFlow on OpenCL devices is here, there is progress being made https://www.codeplay.com/portal/02-14-17-bringing-the-acceleration-of-opencl-to-tensorflow-with-sycl

Answer (score 0):

good news! [tf-coriander](https://github.com/hughperkins/tf-coriander) support amd gpu for tensorflow.
Proven on MBP2017AMD Radeon 560!!

Comment: but tensorflow version is too old and maybe run slower than only use cpu

Comment: That repo is currently broken.  It does not work with the latest Tensorflow build as of this writing (1.11).

Answer (score 0):

With NVIDIA you could easily do it with CUDA but since you have AMD graphics card you can use OpenCL. I have tested it and it worked fine. You can get complete steps here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/60016869/6117565